# Corrupted object inside .git cascading into other issues

Tags: git, github, version-control

One of the Objects at .git/objects was corrupted so I executed `git reset --hard` since I didnt have any major changes locally, which seemed to solve the issue, but now when I try to add files I am getting the following issue:

```
$: git add .
error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument
error: filename.md: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file 'filename.md'
fatal: adding files failed
```

Any solution I tried either returns the corrupted object or end up back here.
Recloning the repo didnt help either.

Edit: Result of git fsck

```bash
D:\repo>git fsck
error: unable to open .git/objects/6d: Function not implemented
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (3421/3421), done.
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 8e4077b76e8099e5008ceef49b1b49defcfeac80
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 8e4077b76e8099e5008ceef49b1b49defcfeac80
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry bdc78aa07d3e46223fc5ee6f64eb090e9d12a5ee
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry bdc78aa07d3e46223fc5ee6f64eb090e9d12a5ee
dangling tree 2380900d8e2a5f26a334798570e543470e0acb90
missing blob 7180171eb3c51c22cdbb4b249d94555172df01b5
```

OS Info:
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Home Single Language
OS Version:                10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621

```bash
D:\repo>git -v
git version 2.41.0.windows.3
```

Comment: What was the first / best clue you have that the object was corrupted? Do you know what the object in question was supposed to be? Do you know how it became corrupted, and if there's a possibility of other objects also being corrupted, or of other problems with the file system you're cloning into?

Comment: Could you try `git fsck` and include the output as a text block in your question?  Also, what OS (including version) and version of Git are you using (`git version`)?

Comment: @IMSoP, so I first realized this when i tried to commit, i got the error along the lines `error: invalid object 100644 <some object name starting with 6d> for 'filename.md'
error: Error building trees`, so, i tried to see whats that bject, but when tried to open 6b folder in .git/objects, it gave popup saying its corrrupted